# Could not find default endpoint element

Tags: wcf

I've derived my own clientbase class. I have a winforms app (client) and the server (windows svc). In the app.config file, I have the following values:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name = "xtest">
        <endpoint
           address  = "net.pipe://localhost/test"
           binding  = "netNamedPipeBinding"
           contract = "ITest"
            />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This is the same as my server. What is amiss?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client you need to have a <client> element, not a <services/service>. You'd have something like the config below.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/test"
                  binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                  contract="ITest" />
    </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I will try that, tomorrow. Will let you know the result.

Comment: Can you post the full exception message?